# Stability Selection - calculating the average number of selected variables

Tags: feature-selection, lasso

I have been reading the Meinshausen paper on Stability Selection that can be found here: [https://stat.ethz.ch/~nicolai/stability.pdf](https://stat.ethz.ch/%7Enicolai/stability.pdf)

From what I understand, the method is to carry out monte carlo simulations and for each data subset generated by the fold, fit a lasso model with different alphas (penalisation parameters).

I am unsure about what the q term referenced in equation (9) and referred to as the average number of selected variables should be calculated.  I believe it should be calculated by finding the mean of the coefficients across all the alphas within a fold and then calculating the mean of this value across all folds.  Is this understanding correct?